# Strange interface design Java

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

At work I came across the following design in a java project:

Consider interfaces `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` as follows:

`interface Bar { public int a(); }`

`interface Baz { public int b(); }`

`interface Foo extends Bar, Baz { public int c(); }`

Now, consider class `FooImpl`:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    private Bar bar;
    private Baz baz;

    public int a() {
        return bar.a();
    }
    public int b() {
        return baz.b();
    }
    public int c() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What are the use cases for this kind of class hierarchy? It seems to me that this introduces a lot of boilerplate and does not add much in terms of abstraction, other than breaking up what could be a large file into smaller files.

Comment: Depends on the concrete semantics for the interfaces and the authors of those. Basically Foo builds upon Bar and Baz (code which works on a Bar or a Baz will also work on a Foo). FooImpl implements one such Foo. If this design makes sense depends on the actual use of Bar and Baz and Foo in the consumer of those interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allows things like this:

```
Foo foo = new FooImpl();
useBar(foo);

public void useBar(Bar bar) {
    bar.a();
}
```

Whether this is useful depends on the *real* context.  Your example code with classes and methods with meaningless names does not support a rational judgement.

The other thing to note is your `FooImpl` is actually implemented as some kind of wrapper for `Bar` and `Baz` instances.  That's not (strictly speaking) an interface design issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understand the case for extending from multiple interfaces, but my question supposed to be targeted more towards the implementation of the class. It seems to me that it introduces a lot of method aliasing, as well as breaking the IDE's ability to create a meaningful call hierarchy (by creating an infinite loop).

Comment: Neither of those things are particularly bad from an (abstracted) design perspective.  (The IDE issue is actually pointing at a short-coming in the IDE design, not the code you are looking at ...) As I said in my answer, you need to look at these things in the context of an actual use-case.  You need to consider what it is doing, why it is doing it, and what the alternatives are.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a workaround for **multiple inheritance** (which is not allowed in Java). You're not showing implementations for `Bar` and `Baz`, but let's suppose they exist:

```
public class BarImpl implements Bar {

    @Override
    public int a() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class BazImpl implements Baz {

    @Override
    public int b() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

You neither have told us how `Bar` and `Baz` attributes are instantiated and set to `FooImpl`, because, if executed as stated in your question, you'll get a `NullPointerException` both in `FooImpl.a()` and `FooImpl.b()`. Again, let's imagine how this could be achieved:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    private Bar bar; // better if final

    private Baz baz; // better if final

    // Constructor to properly initialize bar and baz
    public FooImpl(Bar bar, Baz baz) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baz = baz;
    }

    @Override
    public int a() {
        return bar.a();
    }

    @Override
    public int b() {
        return baz.b();
    }

    @Override
    public int c() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Wiring everything up:

```
Bar bar = new BarImpl();
Baz baz = new BazImpl();

Foo foo = new FooImpl(bar, baz);

int one = foo.bar(); // 1
int two = foo.baz(); // 2
```

In a way, `FooImpl` is "inheriting" from both `BarImpl` and `BazImpl`, though this is achieved by means of delegation.

Answer (score 0):

To do this is really just redirecting fooimpl using its propertie's(bar and baz) "a" method and "b" method